# How to write multiple sheets(WITH SHEETNAMES) in excel using openpyxl and python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried the below code to create excel file with sheetnames. Sheets are created but empty. And one new sheet with only ws2 data is found. Can sonmeone help rewrite this.

```
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws1 = workbook.create_sheet('ONE')
ws2 = workbook.create_sheet('TWO')

ws1 = workbook.active
ws2 = workbook.active

# Construct test worksheets with some content.
ws1['A1'] = 'ID'
ws1['B1'] = 'Text'
ws1['C1'] = 'Category'

ws1['A2'] = '234'
ws1['B2'] = 'Sample'
ws1['C2'] = 'ASD'

ws2['A1'] = 'ID'
ws2['B1'] = 'Text'
ws2['C1'] = 'Category'

ws2['A2'] = '566'
ws2['B2'] = 'Sample'
ws2['C2'] = 'PED'

ws2['A3'] = '896'
ws2['B3'] = 'SAmple'
ws2['C3'] = 'HEAD'

workbook.save('sam.xlsx')
```

Comment: You set ws1 and ws2 to the same object.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Workbook object, it creates an Excel workbook with a default sheet `Sheet`. And executing `workbook.active` returns the active sheet of the Workbook object. (Which is `Sheet` in your case)

So both `ws1` and `ws2` are indicating the sheet `Sheet` for your case resulting from the lines;

```
ws1 = workbook.active
ws2 = workbook.active
```

That is why the code you wrote writes all the cells to `Sheet`.

And as the documentation of the openpyxl indicates, you can achive what you're trying by;

```
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws1 = 'ONE'
ws2 = 'TWO'

workbook.create_sheet(ws1)
workbook.create_sheet(ws2)

workbook[ws1]['A1'] = 'ID'
workbook[ws1]['B1'] = 'Text'
workbook[ws1]['C1'] = 'Category'
workbook[ws1]['A2'] = '234'
workbook[ws1]['B2'] = 'Sample'
workbook[ws1]['C2'] = 'ASD'

workbook[ws2]['A1'] = 'ID'
workbook[ws2]['B1'] = 'Text'
workbook[ws2]['C1'] = 'Category'
workbook[ws2]['A2'] = '566'
workbook[ws2]['B2'] = 'Sample'
workbook[ws2]['C2'] = 'PED'
workbook[ws2]['A3'] = '896'
workbook[ws2]['B3'] = 'SAmple'
workbook[ws2]['C3'] = 'HEAD'

# You can also call the line below to delete the sheet 'Sheet'
workbook.remove(workbook['Sheet'])

workbook.save('sam.xlsx')
```

Comment: If this was what you were looking for, you can mark this answer as the answer of this question, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The first sheet will be created once `workbook.active` is called.

```
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws1 = workbook.active
ws1.title = 'ONE'
ws2 = workbook.create_sheet('TWO')
# Construct test worksheets with some content.
ws1['A1'] = 'ID'
ws1['B1'] = 'Text'
ws1['C1'] = 'Category'

ws1['A2'] = '234'
ws1['B2'] = 'Sample'
ws1['C2'] = 'ASD'

ws2['A1'] = 'ID'
ws2['B1'] = 'Text'
ws2['C1'] = 'Category'

ws2['A2'] = '566'
ws2['B2'] = 'Sample'
ws2['C2'] = 'PED'

ws2['A3'] = '896'
ws2['B3'] = 'SAmple'
ws2['C3'] = 'HEAD'

workbook.save('sam.xlsx')
```

Comment: Official doc: A workbook is always created with at least one worksheet. You can get it by using the Workbook.active.